# What is the origin of Air?

Tags: puranas, belief

When there is a cool breeze, we assume it's all because of the trees and green. But the same trees and green will not give cool breeze in summer. When the tree gets affected by air from another tree or somewhere which i am trying to understand is how the air circulation happens.

But what is the origin of this Air? From where it begins and ends as per science or puranas?